# Setting ColumnDefinitions in code

Tags: c#, wpf, grid, width

I'm wondering if there is a way to set a ColumnDefinition Width to * in code, like you can in the xaml file. When trying to set in code GridLength just has the Auto has an option.

```
<ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You will need to create an instance of the `GridLength` data type and specify `GridUnitType.Star`

```
col.Width = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star);
```

Comment: Interesting. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Fantastic! You are my hero!